# Clustering values in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe with 76 columns. 1st column contains date values and the other 75 columns are groundwater levels form 75 different boreholes. I want to cluster the boreholes based on the trend (boreholes that follow the same pattern are grouped together). How can I do this in python?

Here is a sample of my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000],
'borehole1': [53, 43, 33, 22, 18],
'borehole2': [50, 40, 30, 50, 40],
'borehole3': [22, 32, 42, 32, 13],
'borehole4': [60, 65, 82, 72, 60],
'borehole5': [80, 70, 60, 80, 70],
'borehole6': [43, 33, 22, 18, 13]
}) 

df.plot()
```

In this example I would therefore have 3 clusters:

- borehole1 & borehole 6 >> cluster 1
- borehole2 & borehole 5 >> cluster 2
- borehole 4 & borehole 3 >> cluster 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The K-Means algo is perfect for this!  Here is a sample (below).  Just point the X and y to your specific dataset and set the 'K' to 3 (already done for you in this example).

```
# K-MEANS CLUSTERING
# Importing Modules
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
# Loading dataset
iris_df = datasets.load_iris()

# Declaring Model
model = KMeans(n_clusters=3)

# Fitting Model
model.fit(iris_df.data)

# Predicitng a single input
predicted_label = model.predict([[7.2, 3.5, 0.8, 1.6]])

# Prediction on the entire data
all_predictions = model.predict(iris_df.data)

# Printing Predictions
print(predicted_label)
print(all_predictions)


# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :3]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1],X[:,2], 
            c=all_predictions, edgecolor='red', s=40, alpha = 0.5)
plt.set_title("First three PCA directions")
plt.set_xlabel("Educational_Degree")
plt.set_ylabel("Gross_Monthly_Salary")
plt.set_zlabel("Claim_Rate")
plt.dist = 10
plt
```

[image]

See this link for more info.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html

Comment: This code does not run properly because you have overwritten the plt import with different content. All the lines after creating the figure should start with someting like `ax` or `ax.` instead of `plt` or `plt.` . 
Then you may have to add `plt.show()` to actually see a plot (on some systems)